# Change default GeoModelAdmin to OSMGeoAdmin

Tags: django, geodjango, wagtail

I tried to naively add it to `admin.py` like I normally would.

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin 
from project.models import ProjectMap

admin.site.register(ProjectMap, admin.OSMGeoAdmin)
```

I tried specifying the widget:

```
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [ 
    FieldPanel('location', widget='django.contrib.gis.forms.widgets.OSMWidget'),
]
```

But it stil shows the default satellite image from GeoModelAdmin.

Here is the basic models i'm working with.

```
class ProjectPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date", null=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('date'),
        ], heading="Project information"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        ], heading='Project'),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Gallery images"),
        InlinePanel('project_map', label="Project location")
    ]


class ProjectMap(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(ProjectPage, related_name='project_map')
    city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    country = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    location = PointField(blank=True, null=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('city'),
            FieldPanel('address'),
            FieldPanel('country'),
            FieldPanel('location'),
        ], heading="Location")
    ]
```

And the documentation I am following:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/forms-api/#widget-classes
- http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/pages/panels.html#wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers.FieldPanel.widget

Comment: The `widget` argument on `FieldPanel` needs to be a widget object or class, rather than a string path - can you try `from django.contrib.gis.forms.widgets import OSMWidget` and then `FieldPanel('location', widget=OSMWidget)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@gasman is correct!**

If you take a look at Django docs about [specifying widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#specifying-widgets) you will see that an object is passed and not a string:

```
from django.contrib.gis.forms.widgets import OSMWidget

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel('location', widget=OSMWidget),]
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the code. I get no errors, but the widget doesn't change in the admin.

Comment: It didn't work because ProjectMap was a ParentalKey to ProjectPage. If that isn't the case, it works.